# Can I iterate object rendered by mustache?

Tags: php, mustache

I have table generated by mustache loop that looks like this:

**names.mustache**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                #
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#allnames}}
        {{#active}}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{count}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{name}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {{/active}}
    {{/allnames}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I want to iterate count so that my table can have row numbers. basically, i initialized `$count=1`. How can I implement that with clean efficient code? or is there a better simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**
For **Mustache**, you need to create a function

```
var data = {
    items: allnames,
    , index: function() {
        return ++window['index']||(window['index']=0);
    }
}
```

and then use `{{index}}` inside the loop

**originally**

Sorry, I was thinking of handlebars which works as below (see correct answer above)

Use `{{@index}}`

```
{{#allnames}}
    {{name}} is {{@index}}
{{/allnames}}
```

**Note**: index starts from zero

Comment: it's not working man. do you have any idea why? i replaced `{{count}}` with `{{@index}}`

Comment: inside `mustache.js` ?